In Molang, does it matter whether you use q. or query.?
I have been making a Minecraft Bedrock Addon in bridge. for the past few days and have made a surprising amount of progress.
But today I noticed that sometimes Blockbench uses q. and query. in different parts of files. In the files I've been referencing, they use q., which is correct or are they both? I think q. is a short way of writing it, but I'm not entirely sure. I am 95% sure that query. is correct but am not so sure about q.

According to the official Documentation, there are multiple aliases:
context ->  c
query   ->  q
temp    ->  t
variable->  v

so yes, q and query are interchangeable
